# Running netflix conductor with standalone elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, netflix, netflix-conductor

How to configure Netflix conductor to run standalone elastic search rather than embedded elastic search ?

Comment: Please provide more details related to the question. For example: The steps that you have tried, relevant links to documentations, what's the expected behaviour, and what is failing exactly.
This will enable people to help you better.

Comment: I have downloaded kitchen sink example  from [link](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/metadata/kitchensink/). In this [link]https://netflix.github.io/conductor/server/ - they have specified configuration parameters but I am not getting which file it is in the app.

Comment: This line in the link:
Conductor server uses a property file based configuration. The property file is passed to the Main class as a command line argument.

Comment: java -jar conductor-server-all-VERSION.jar `[PATH TO PROPERTY FILE]` [log4j.properties file path]

Comment: Make a file and put the path in here

Comment: Was this all, that you were asking about?

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. But to make conductor run with standalone elasticsearch what are properties to be changed in the file you mentioned.

Comment: My standalone elasticsearch is running on publish address 192.168.0.24:9300. So I changed the configuration property workflow.elasticsearch.url=192.168.0.24:9300 it is throwing error

Comment: I ran command - java -jar conductor-server-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar  "w:\apurva\kedar\es.properties"

Comment: sorry, elasticsearch is working error is with dynomite. Thanks a lot:):)

Comment: No worries :) Happens a lot.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a conductor-config.properties just make sure you have these pointing to the valid elasticsearch you have up and running:

```
workflow.elasticsearch.instanceType=EXTERNAL
workflow.elasticsearch.url=http://elasticsearch:9200
```

Then should be able to run conductor up with that config:
    java conductor-server-2.15.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar conductor-config.properties

https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/blob/master/es5-persistence/src/main/java/com/netflix/conductor/dao/es5/index/ElasticSearchRestDAOV5.java
You can inspect this as an example, swapping the elastic container by your own, modifying the conductor-config.properties. It will be copied in when you run:
check out https://github.com/s50600822/conductor-cheat
inside the repo just do

```
docker-compose up
```

Check out https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/blob/master/es5-persistence/src/main/java/com/netflix/conductor/dao/es5/index/ElasticSearchRestDAOV5.java for other options.

Answer (score 0):

To add external elastic search we need to follow code changes as mentioned in 
below link.
*https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/tree/master/es5-persistence*.
And rebuild jar and run conductor server again with properties.

if you still get errors , I suggest to follow below link
*https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/issues/489*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standalone installation of elasticsearch2 or elasticsearch5 because the associated support classes are already provided with Netflix Conductor binary.

To configure externally you have to do the following

- Install and configure standalone elasticsearch. By default the
  installation would expose 2 ports 9200/http or 9300/tcp.
- Update server.properties file with the host and port so that the
  communication will start happening with the standalone instance of
  elasticsearch.

Hope this helps.